# Select tag with onchange event always redirect

Tags: javascript, html

if I use onchange event

```
<select ="" name="ifin" id="ifin" onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

then in option I write `<option value="#">HPL</option>`, does the hpl have no value? or can I still fill the value in another way?

Comment: `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `this.value`

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you use `value="#"` then the value is the string `"#"`.

Comment: if i use the onchange event it will not redirect to another html

Comment: That's right, because `#` doesn't contain another URL.

Comment: It's just a hash in the current URL.

Comment: but if fill the value like this `value="hpl"` it show the html doesn't exist

Comment: Of course. It's the same as using something like `<a href="hpl">` and clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

It's value is "#", and you can also fill it in dynamically.

Comment: what do u mean dynamically?

Comment: Through script.

Comment: You can change the value through javascript or jquery: 
for example, to change the value of the first option dynamically in jquery:
$("#ifin").children()[0].value = "popo"

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="#HPL">HPL</option>
```